# pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed

Tags: python, langchain

I am creating a langchain agent. It works on google colab but not on my computer. I tried reinstalling and I tried on a virtual machine but that gave a different error.

Here is the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '*cffi_backend'
> thread '' panicked at 'Python API call failed', C:\Users\runneradmin.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\pyo3-0.15.2\src\err\mod.rs:582:5
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\OneDrive\Documents\VS Code\AVA\autogpt\main.py", line 2, in 
> from langchain.llms.base import LLM
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain_*init**.py", line 6, in 
> from langchain.agents import MRKLChain, ReActChain, SelfAskWithSearchChain
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\agents_*init*_.py", line 2, in 
> from langchain.agents.agent import (
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 15, in 
> from langchain.agents.tools import InvalidTool
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\agents\tools.py", line 8, in 
> from langchain.tools.base import BaseTool, Tool, tool
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\tools_*init*_.py", line 13, in 
> from langchain.tools.gmail import (
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\tools\gmail_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
> from langchain.tools.gmail.create_draft import GmailCreateDraft
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\tools\gmail\create_draft.py", line 11, in 
> from langchain.tools.gmail.base import GmailBaseTool
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\langchain\tools\gmail\base.py", line 17, in 
> from googleapiclient.discovery import Resource
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 45, in 
> from google.oauth2 import service_account
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 77, in 
> from google.auth import *service_account_info
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\auth_service_account_info.py", line 22, in 
> from google.auth import crypt
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\auth\crypt_*init**.py", line 43, in 
> from google.auth.crypt import rsa
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\auth\crypt\rsa.py", line 20, in 
> from google.auth.crypt import *cryptography_rsa
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\google\auth\crypt_cryptography_rsa.py", line 25, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization_*init**.py", line 16, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.base import (
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\base.py", line 9, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.types import (
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\types.py", line 8, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import (
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\dsa.py", line 10, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import utils as asym_utils
> File "C:\Users\yasee.STUDY-COMPUTER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py", line 6, in 
> from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import asn1

Here is the code:

```
from typing_extensions import Text
from langchain.llms.base import LLM
from typing import Optional, List, Mapping, Any
import gpt4free
from gpt4free import Provider, forefront

class freegpt(LLM):
@property
def \_llm_type(self) -\> str:
return "custom"

    def _call(self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> str:
        if isinstance(stop, list):
            stop = stop + ["\n###","\nObservation:", "\nObservations:"]
            
        response = gpt4free.Completion.create(provider=Provider.UseLess, prompt=prompt)
        response = response['text']
        response = response.split("Observation", maxsplit=1)[0]
    
        return response
    
    @property
    def _identifying_params(self) -> Mapping[str, Any]:
        """Get the identifying parameters."""
        return {}

from langchain.agents import Tool, AgentExecutor, LLMSingleActionAgent, AgentOutputParser
from langchain.prompts import StringPromptTemplate
from langchain import OpenAI, SerpAPIWrapper, LLMChain
from typing import List, Union
from langchain.schema import AgentAction, AgentFinish
from langchain import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.llms import VertexAI
import re

# Define which tools the agent can use to answer user queries

search = SerpAPIWrapper(serpapi_api_key='cc528133d4712378d13ee296bb2965e4c9d511ab22bd7c8819bd61bdc9d66c9c')
tools = \[
Tool(
name = "Search",
func=search.run,
description="useful for when you need to answer questions about current events"
)
\]

# Set up the base template

template = """Answer the following questions as best you can, but speaking as a pirate might speak. You have access to the following tools:

{tools}

Always use the following format:

Question: the input question you must answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take, should be one of the \[{tools}\]. It should just be the name of the tool(eg. Search)
Action Input: the input to the action or tool chosen in Action.
Observation: the result of the action. do nto include this in your answer back. it will be provided with the correct info from the tool when it comes back.
... (this Thought/Action/Action Input/Observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer
Final Answer: the final answer to the original input question

Begin!

Question: {input}
{agent_scratchpad}"""

# Set up a prompt template

class CustomPromptTemplate(StringPromptTemplate):
\# The template to use
template: str
\# The list of tools available
tools: List\[Tool\]

    def format(self, **kwargs) -> str:
        # Get the intermediate steps (AgentAction, Observation tuples)
        # Format them in a particular way
        intermediate_steps = kwargs.pop("intermediate_steps")
        thoughts = ""
        for action, observation in intermediate_steps:
            thoughts += action.log
            thoughts += f"\nObservation: {observation}\nThought: "
        # Set the agent_scratchpad variable to that value
        kwargs["agent_scratchpad"] = thoughts
        # Create a tools variable from the list of tools provided
        kwargs["tools"] = "\n".join([f"{tool.name}: {tool.description}" for tool in self.tools])
        # Create a list of tool names for the tools provided
        kwargs["tool_names"] = ", ".join([tool.name for tool in self.tools])
        return self.template.format(**kwargs)

prompt = CustomPromptTemplate(
template=template,
tools=tools,
\# This omits the `agent_scratchpad`, `tools`, and `tool_names` variables because those are generated dynamically
\# This includes the `intermediate_steps` variable because that is needed
input_variables=\["input", "intermediate_steps"\]
)

class CustomOutputParser(AgentOutputParser):

    def parse(self, llm_output: str) -> Union[AgentAction, AgentFinish]:
        print(llm_output)
        # Check if agent should finish
        if "Final Answer:" in llm_output:
            return AgentFinish(
                # Return values is generally always a dictionary with a single `output` key
                # It is not recommended to try anything else at the moment :)
                return_values={"output": llm_output.split("Final Answer:")[-1].strip()},
                log=llm_output,
            )
        # Parse out the action and action input
        regex = r"Action\s*\d*\s*:(.*?)\nAction\s*\d*\s*Input\s*\d*\s*:[\s]*(.*)"
        match = re.search(regex, llm_output, re.DOTALL)
        if not match:
            raise ValueError(f"Could not parse LLM output: `{llm_output}`")
        action = match.group(1).strip()
        action_input = match.group(2)
        # Return the action and action input
        return AgentAction(tool=action, tool_input=action_input.strip(" ").strip('"'), log=llm_output)

output_parser = CustomOutputParser()

# LLM chain consisting of the LLM and a prompt

llm = freegpt()

llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
tool_names = \[tool.name for tool in tools\]
agent = LLMSingleActionAgent(
llm_chain=llm_chain,
output_parser=output_parser,
stop=\["\\nObservation:"\],
allowed_tools=tool_names
)
agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(agent=agent, tools=tools, verbose=True)
agent_executor.run("How many people live in canada")
```

I tried to first reinstall everything but it kept giving errors.